# Prepend to ant classpath instead of append

Tags: java, ant, classpath

Below is a sample ant file for the purpose of this question.

Target "test1" is called from "test" using antcall. Now, when I have some classes having same fully qualified class names, I want the classes from test1.jar to be loaded first but it looks like test1.jar is appended to the classpath and hence classes from test.jar are picked instead.

Is there any way to reset/clear the classpath for target test1 or prepend test1.jar to the classpath so that classes from it are loaded.

```
<project name="TestProj" basedir=".">  
  <target name="test">      
    <java inputstring="" fork="true" failonerror="true" dir=".">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="C:/bb/" includes="test.jar"/>
      </classpath>      
    </java>
  </presetdef> 
  <antcall target="test1"/>
  </target>

  <target name="test1"> 
    <java inputstring="" fork="true" failonerror="true" dir=".">         
      <classpath>       
        <path location="c:/test1.jar"/>
      </classpath>
      <jvmarg line="-Xms64m -Xmx512m"/>
      <jvmarg line="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"/>
    </java>
  </presetdef>
  </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  <path id="test.classpath">
    <fileset dir="C:/bb/" includes="test.jar"/>
    <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
  </path>

  <path id="test1.classpath">
    <pathelement location="c:/test1.jar"/>
  </path>

<project name="TestProj" basedir=".">  
  <target name="test">      
    <java inputstring="" fork="true" failonerror="true" dir=".">
      <classpath>
        <path refid="test.classpath"/>
      </classpath>      
    </java>
  </presetdef> 
  <antcall target="test1"/>
  </target>

  <target name="test1"> 
    <java inputstring="" fork="true" failonerror="true" dir=".">         
      <classpath>       
        <path refid="test1.classpath"/>
      </classpath>
      <jvmarg line="-Xms64m -Xmx512m"/>
      <jvmarg line="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"/>
    </java>
  </presetdef>
  </target>
```